# Is there a way to configure Cassandra to use port 7000 for internode comms but use port 443 to connect to other nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, openshift

Is there a way to tell cassandra to: "listen to the port 7000 for intra node connection but when you try to connect to other cassandra hosts use another port like 443?"

Basically same as Elasticsearch where you have `http.port` and `http.publish_port` [Elasticsearch configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#http-settings)

Our scenario is:

- we have a cassandra cluster deployed in Openshift using the bitnami helm chart
- now we want to deploy other cassandra ring/dc in another Openshift cluster
- then we want to connect together the 2 cassandra rings deployed in 2 different Openshift clusters
- we have a restriction: we have to use an openshift route to expose the traffic outside an openshift cluster, and the openshift route works only on port 443 but I cannot configure the port 443 in docker/cassandra since that is a privileged port

Comment: Notice, you can't "connect together" two different clusters.

Comment: I would use the same cluster name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra nodes use the gossip protocol for internode communications and by default uses port `7000`:

```
storage_port: 7000
```

This port is exclusively used for **private communications** between nodes which is typically configured on a private address/network (`listen_address`).

Apps/clients use a completely separate port (CQL client port `9042`) to connect to the cluster which is usually on a completely separate **public network** (`rpc_address`):

```
native_transport_port: 9042
```

You can configure whatever port you want/need in `conf/cassandra.yaml`. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not what I asked.